# I'm getting a job (meaning)

Tags: meaning, grammar

I'm trying to understand the meaning of **I'm getting a job** but I can't. I know that it doesn't mean **I'm looking for a job** nor **I got a job**.

I want to understand the meaning of it because I saw a few sentences using "**I'm getting something**" such as:
*I'm getting a job*.
*I'm getting a car*.
*I'm getting a puppy*.

So what does it really mean?
And when do you use it?

Comment: It can mean *either* of the things you say it doesn't mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I'm getting a job" generally describes the point in between "I'm looking for a job" and "I got a job". It means that it has been arranged and planned for, but has not happened yet. There's a certain degree of confidence involved, implying that at some point in the future, you will be able to say "I got a job". (Or "I got a puppy".)

However, because of the variability of the confidence, as Jason points out in his comment, "I'm getting a job" can, in fact, mean either "I'm looking for a job" or "I got a job". An optimistic person may say "I'm getting a job" whilst job hunting, and a person who has received a formal job offer may excitedly relay to others that "I'm getting a job" even though they have already gotten the job.

Answer (score -1):

When something is arranged plan in the future you can use it with "ing". I think it means there is a certainty that I am going to get a job.as another example:
“I’m going to play football on Saturday”

You have made a plan in your head but possibly not taken any real action to confirm it. Also, playing football on Saturday is probably not a regular event for you.

“I’m playing football on Saturday”

You have made a plan and taken some real action to confirm it (e.g. called your friends or booked a place to play). In this case, it’s likely that playing football on Saturdays is a common activity for you.

Comment: 'I'm getting a..." means that arrangements are in progress for you to have this thing, but it isn't in your possession yet.